# pandas fill in missing index from other dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I wanted to know if there is a way for me to merge / re-join the missing rows simply by index.

My original way to approach is just to cleanly separate df1 into df1_cleaned and df1_untouched, and then join them back together. But I thought there's probably an easier way to re-join the two df2 since I didn't change the index. I tried outer merge with left_index and right_index but was left with the dupe columns with suffix to clean.

df1

| index | colA | colB | colC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | California | 123 | abc |
| 1 | New York | 456 | def |
| 2 | Texas | 789 | ghi |

df2 (subset of df1 and cleaned)

| index | colA | colB | colC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | California | 321 | abc |
| 2 | Texas | 789 | ihg |

end-result

| index | colA | colB | colC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | California | 321 | abc |
| 1 | New York | 456 | def |
| 2 | Texas | 789 | ihg |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `combine_first` or `update`:

```
df_out = df2.combine_first(df1)
```

or, `pd.DataFrame.update` (which is an inplace operation and will overwrite df1):

```
df1.update(df2)
```

Output:

```
             colA   colB colC
index                        
0      California  321.0  abc
1        New York  456.0  def
2           Texas  789.0  ihg
```

Comment: I know I am changing data here. But `update` doesn't update if the other "cleaned" dataframe has NaN values right? (which may not be the case usually perhaps)

Comment: @SomeDude You put the dataframe you want to update first. In this case df1 is updated with df2 values and df2 remains unchanged.

Comment: @SomeDude here the value in colc for index 2 changes from ghi to ihg in df1.

Comment: I understand that. But if the value is 'NaN' in place of "ihg" in df2 the update won't change it to "NaN".

Comment: True, but then you can mask NaN `.mask(df1.isna())` by appending to statement.

Answer (score 1):

You can get difference of index, and add the missing index from df1 to df_result after reindexing df2

```
df_result = df2.reindex(df1.index)
missing_index = df1.index.difference(df2.index)
df_result.loc[missing_index] = df1.loc[missing_index]
```

print(df_result)

```
         colA   colB colC
0  California  321.0  abc
1    New York  456.0  def
2       Texas  789.0  ihg
```